# Marshal.Copy() causes System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, copy, marshalling, stack-overflow

I encountered a **System.StackOverflowException** problem when I was trying to `Marshal.Copy()`

Here is the screen shot of the code where exception happens:

[image]

Here is the function:

```
private static void ImageUpdate(IntPtr returnArray, ref int channels)
        {
            if (_prevTickCount == 0)
            {
                _sumTickCount = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                _sumTickCount = _sumTickCount * .75 + (Environment.TickCount - _prevTickCount) * .25;
            }

            //only copy to the buffer when pixel data is not being read
            if (_pixelDataReady == false)
            {
                int width = 0;
                int height = 0;

                if (false == GetImageDimensions(ref width, ref height))
                {
                    return;
                }

                _dataLength = width * height;

                _colorChannels = channels;

                if ((_pixelData == null) || (_pixelData.Length != (_dataLength * _colorChannels)))
                {
                    _pixelData = new short[_dataLength * _colorChannels];
                    //_pixelDataHistogram = new int[_colorChannels][];
                    _pixelDataHistogram = new int[MAX_CHANNELS][];

                    if (_colorChannels == 1)
                    {
                        _pixelDataByte = new byte[_dataLength];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _pixelDataByte = new byte[_dataLength * 3];
                    }

                    //for (int i = 0; i < _colorChannels; i++)
                    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHANNELS; i++)
                    {
                        _pixelDataHistogram[i] = new int[PIXEL_DATA_HISTOGRAM_SIZE];
                    }
                }

                //2^n  == FULL_RANGE_NORMALIZATION_FACTOR
                const int SHIFT_VALUE = 6;
                switch (_colorChannels)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            Marshal.Copy(returnArray, _pixelData, 0, _dataLength * _colorChannels);

                            //factor is derived by taking CAMERA_MAX_INTENSITY_VALUE/256
                            //const double FULL_RANGE_NORMALIZATION_FACTOR = 64.0;

                            //clear the histogram
                            for (int i = 0; i < PIXEL_DATA_HISTOGRAM_SIZE; i++)
                            {
                                _pixelDataHistogram[0][i] = 0;
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < _dataLength * _colorChannels; i++)
                            {
                                double valHist;

                                if (_pixelData[i] < 0)
                                {
                                    valHist = (_pixelData[i] + 32768) >> SHIFT_VALUE;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    valHist = (_pixelData[i]) >> SHIFT_VALUE;
                                }

                                _pixelDataHistogram[0][(byte)valHist]++;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        {
                            Marshal.Copy(returnArray, _pixelData, 0, _dataLength * _colorChannels);
                        }
                        break;
                }

                _dataWidth = width;
                _dataHeight = height;
                _pixelDataReady = true;
                ThorLog.Instance.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 1, "ImageUpdate pixeldata updated");
            }
            else
            {
                ThorLog.Instance.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 1, "ImageUpdate pixeldata not ready");
            }

            _prevTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
        }
```

The whole idea is to copy image buffer from native code. This exception occurs only when image size is large 4K X 4K, but I dont have a problem processing a size below that.

I have no idea how I should correct this. Anyone care to educate? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58450/discussion-between-clever-neologism-and-ono).

Comment: What's the types of _pixelData and _dataLength?

Comment: @EricLemes short[] _pixelData; int[] _dataLength;

Comment: returnArray is a IntPtr, what suggest that it has some unmanaged memory inside. My only guess is that the length (_dataLength * _colorChannel) is over the size of the returnArray, causing an undefined behavior. The error should be different from Stack Overflow, but I don't have a best explanation until now.

Comment: @EricLemes this may sound stupid, but in this case returnArray is the source, and _pixelData is the destination. So why does it matter when the size of the destination is larger than the size of the source?

Comment: StackOverflow does not always indicate recursion. Presumably, Marshal.Copy is writing to the stack, and your image is too large to fit.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Is there any chance to ask the stack to accept my large image?

Comment: Hmm.. Actually, not so sure that's the problem now. Your array is already allocated before you Marshal.Copy, plus it seems to not be a local variable, so it's probably on the heap anyway. You can increase the stack size (http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/rickm/archive/2008/04/22/increasing-the-size-of-your-stack-net-memory-management-part-3.aspx), but it's not really the best idea, and may not fix this anyway.

Comment: If you can get this down to a small self-contained program that reproduces the issue (maybe with a sample image, if necessary), that would help people look into it.

Comment: @Ono, you're right. Shame on me. In this case, if the "length" parameter is bigger than the size of the buffer allocated for source, it will read bad data after the buffer ends. It shouldn't give an error like stack overflow, the supposed behavior in this case is bad data being sent to the dest array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traced it down, eventually, if was the `returnArray` which is not `newed` large enough to cause this problem.